# Backbone.js collection comparator sort by multiple fields?

Tags: javascript, sorting, backbone.js

```
  this.col = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: M,
    comparator: function(item) {
      return item.get("level");
    }
  });
```

This above code sorts items by level. I want to sort by level, then by title. Can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: There is support for sort-style comparators since the beginning of 2012. Just accept 2 arguments and return -1, 0 or 1. https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/commit/6b3ff7b0359510917d9ead8c8e16a7457eef05ef

Answer (score 73, accepted):

@amchang87's answer definitely works, but another that I found worked is simply returning an array of the sortable fields:

```
this.col = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: M,
    comparator: function(item) {
      return [item.get("level"), item.get("title")]
    }
});
```

I haven't tested this in multiple browsers yet as I think it relies on JS' behavior in sort order for arrays (based on their contents). It definitely works in WebKit.

Comment: There is support for sort-style comparators since the beginning of 2012. Just accept 2 arguments and return -1, 0 or 1. https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/commit/6b3ff7b0359510917d9ead8c8e16a7457eef05ef

Comment: So straight-forward, this technique is. Here's an example in CoffeeScript: https://gist.github.com/jhabdas/9822535

Comment: Note that (at least in Webkit) the two fields will be compared as strings. If you're trying to do number sorting you're going to end up with 1, 10, 2, 20, 200, etc.

Comment: @RobW: Not quite, it will actually end up comparing the stringified arrays rather than their elements so this answer is incorrect and will only work by accident.

Comment: @RobW You are correct. How can I achieve the same, If i have 2 numeric fields rather than text fields ?

Comment: @Jyothu Make a custom comparator that turns the strings into numbers using `parseInt()` and then compares them. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 8):

String concatenation works fine when sorting multiple fields in ascending order, but it didn't work for me because 1) I had to support asc/desc per field and 2) certain fields were number field (i.e., I want 10 to come after 2 if it is ascending). So, below was a comparator function I used and worked OK for my needs. It assumes the backbone collection has a variable assigned with 'sortConfig', which is an array of JSON objects with field name and sort order direction. For example,

```
{
    "sort" : [
        {
            "field": "strField",
            "order": "asc"
         },
         {
             "field": "numField",
             "order": "desc"
         },
         ...
     ]
}
```

With the JSON object above assigned as 'sortConfig' to the collection, the function below will make Backbone sort by strField in ascending order first, then sort by numField in descending order, etc. If no sort order is specified, it sorts ascending by default.

```
multiFieldComparator: function(one, another) {
    // 'this' here is Backbone Collection
    if (this.sortConfig) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.sortConfig.length; i++) {
            if (one.get(this.sortConfig[i].field) > another.get(this.sortConfig[i].field)) {
                return ("desc" != this.sortConfig[i].order) ? 1 : -1;
            } else if (one.get(this.sortConfig[i].field) == another.get(this.sortConfig[i].field)) {
                // do nothing but let the loop move further for next layer comparison
            } else {
                return ("desc" != this.sortConfig[i].order) ? -1 : 1;
            }
        }
    }
    // if we exited out of loop without prematurely returning, the 2 items being
    // compared are identical in terms of sortConfig, so return 0
    // Or, if it didn't get into the if block due to no 'sortConfig', return 0
    // and let the original order not change.
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Returning an array is not consistent if you need to sort descending and some ascending...

I created a small set of functions which can be used to return the relevant comparison integer back to Backbone Comparator function:

[backbone-collection-multisort](https://github.com/mindmelting/backbone-collection-multisort)

Answer (score 1):

The main thing is that Backbone sorts by a single relative value of one item to another. So it's not directly possible to sort twice in a single collection but I'd try this.

```
this.col = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: M,
    comparator: function(item) {
      // make sure this returns a string!
      return item.get("level") + item.get("title");
    }
});
```

What this will do is return a string of like "1Cool", "1title", "2newTitle" ...
Javascript should sort the strings by the numerical character first then each character afterwards. But this will only work as long as your levels have the same amount of digits. IE "001title" vs "200title". The main idea though is that you need to produce two comparable objects, line a number or string, that can be compared to each other based on one criteria.

Other solution would be to use underscore to "groupby" your level then use "sortby" to manually sort each level group then manually replace the underlying collection with this newly created array. You can probably setup a function to do this whenever the collection "changes".

Comment: If I'm understanding the 'groupby' method that would mess up my data modeling wouldn't it? The first solution is kinda nice though, so thanks for that.

Comment: Not sure this is the best way to do it. For example, if you had 2 models: model1-> level: 1, title: "1-thing"; model2 -> level: 10, title: "-thing", then you would expect it to be sorted model1, model2 - but by that comparator, it would be comparing string "11-thing" and "10-thing", so would be sorted in the wrong order

Comment: This is functional identical to trying to sort by an array, returning `[1,'x']` from a single argument comparator function will sort by the string `"1,x"` instead of comparing the elements.

Answer (score 0):

"inspired" in hyong answer.

This also allows you to change the data before compare it, valueTransforms is an object, if there is an attribute in that object that has a function, it will be used.

```
    /*
     * @param {Object} sortOrders ie: 
     * {
     *     "description": "asc",
     *     "duedate": "desc",
     * }
     * @param {Object} valueTransforms
     */
    setMultiFieldComparator: function(sortOrders, valueTransforms) {
        var newSortOrders = {}, added = 0;
        _.each(sortOrders, function(sortOrder, sortField) {
            if (["asc", "desc"].indexOf(sortOrder) !== -1) {
                newSortOrders[sortField] = sortOrder;
                added += 1;
            }
        });
        if (added) {
            this.comparator = this._multiFieldComparator
                .bind(this, newSortOrders, valueTransforms || this.model.prototype.valueTransforms || {});
        } else {
            this.comparator = null;
        }
    },

    _multiFieldComparator: function(sortOrders, valueTransforms, one, another) {
        var retVal = 0;
        if (sortOrders) {
            _.every(sortOrders, function(sortOrder, sortField) {
                var oneValue = one.get(sortField),
                    anotherValue = another.get(sortField);
                if (valueTransforms[sortField] instanceof Function) {
                    oneValue = valueTransforms[sortField](oneValue);
                    anotherValue = valueTransforms[sortField](anotherValue);
                }
                if (oneValue > anotherValue) {
                    retVal = ("desc" !== sortOrder) ? 1 : -1;
                } else if (oneValue < anotherValue) {
                    retVal = ("desc" !== sortOrder) ? -1 : 1;
                } else {
                    //continue
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
        return retVal;
    },
```