# Backbone.js collection with multiple sorts

Tags: javascript, sorting, collections, backbone.js

I have a todo list with name and date. I'd like to be able to sort the list using either the title or to the date. How would I do this? Comparator allows only one type of sorting.

Thanks.

Comment: Can I ask why you don't want to reset the collection ? There are reset triggers (for views) for this exact reason. i.e. when your sorting changes through a reset then your view re-renders.

Comment: You're right, I see no disadvantage in resetting the whole collection. Thanks.

Comment: It is normal to `reset` a collection when data changes, in your case the entire collection, even though it's the same data but in different order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a method:

```
collection.reset(collection.sortBy(function(item){
    return item.get(sortingFIeld);
}))
```

Where sortBy returns a new, sorted array that is passed as argument to reset. SortingField is the string property of the model.

Comment: He specifically said he doesn't want to use reset. And now he edited that out :P Not your fault.

Comment: I am me though lol. I edited that out because for the moment that's the solution I can think of.

Comment: Can you expand your answer? I'm dealing with the same thing and wondering where you specify which attribute (title or date) to sort by.

Comment: Sure, here's the complete code. It's just one line. Backbone.js' site has more info. Search "sortBy" on the site and it should be the second result.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to implement more logic into the comparator so that you can abstract away some of the sorting logic:

```
var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: myModel,
    order: 'name'

    comparator: function(model) {
        if (this.order === 'name') {
            return model.get('name');
        } else {
            return model.get('date'); //or modify date into a numeric value
        }
    }
});
```

Then to change how you want it sorted:

```
myCollection.order = 'date';
myCollection.sort();
```

This will call the comparator function and sort it this way.

You can listen for the resorting in a view:

```
this.listenTo(myCollection,'sort',this.render);
```

This has the added advantage that every time a model is added, it calls the comparator and sorts it using whatever your current setting is, because the sorting method is stored in the collection.

Comment: +1 for this answer. Options are how you pass information between your application that the functions need.

Answer (score 3):

You may need to look at [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921667/backbone-js-collection-comparator-sort-by-multiple-fields), here is the solution provided in that post:

```
comparator: function(item) {
    return [item.get("level"), item.get("title")]
}
```