# Sorting backbone collection on three model attributes

Tags: javascript, sorting, backbone.js

I looked into http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator and for one model attribute, as shown in the example, the sorting working just fine. However, I want to sort on multiple attributes and the following post suggested that this could be done for more than one attribute:

[Backbone.js collection comparator sort by multiple fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921667/backbone-js-collection-comparator-sort-by-multiple-fields)

```
comparator: function(item) {
  return [item.get("level"), item.get("title")]
}
```

I am able to sort on two attributes as suggested in the example above, however, if I add one additional attribute (a 3rd attribute), the sorting doesn't work on that third attribute.

Can someone explain why this works for one and two attributes, but not for three?

Below is how I define the comparator:

```
var aCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Model,
    comparator: function(item){
      return [item.get('uid'), item.get('vid'), item.get('wid')];
    },
    ...
});
```

Comment: That answer you reference is flat out wrong and will only work by accident, please ignore it. If you want to sort by more than one attribute, use a two-argument `comparator` (which behaves like the `comparator` function you pass to [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)) and do the attribute by attribute comparisons by hand.

Comment: @muistooshort thanks for the feedback. I sort of needed to know from more experienced devs is that solution was appropriate, so I'll look into your suggestion for now.

Comment: hyong's answer to that question is much better than the (sadly) upvoted accepted answer. It is a shame that so many people upvote answers without understanding them.

Comment: @muistooshort i agree, specially when you come here for some clarity and then end up being led in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be clear, I am using require.js with backbone. To solve this problem, I did a ton of Googling an then tried the following, which worked. When loading up my collection, I have created a `comparator` function that takes in two arguments. Example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thehme/hydyeejz/)

```
comparator: function(a, b){

var fields = ['uid','vid','wid'],
            directions = ['asc', 'asc', 'asc'],
            cmpOn;

        cmpOn = _.find(fields, function(c){
           return a.attributes[c] != b.attributes[c];
        });

        if(!cmpOn) return 0;

        if ( ( directions[_.indexOf( fields, cmpOn )] || 'asc' ).toLowerCase() == 'asc' ) {
            return a.attributes[cmpOn] > b.attributes[cmpOn] ? 1 : -1;
        } else {
            return a.attributes[cmpOn] < b.attributes[cmpOn] ? 1 : -1;
        }

}
```